# Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed. Dropdown Error

Tags: android, kotlin

I added a dropdown but the data is not coming when opening the dropdown.

It gives this error :

"Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed."

My Code

```
    private fun warehousesHedefDepo() {
        var listHedefDepo: ArrayList<String>
        var mutableMap: MutableMap<String, String>
        viewModel.getDataDemakDepolar(apiUrl)
        viewModel.liveDataDepolar.myObserve(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            success = { list ->
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                mutableMap = mutableMapOf()
                mutableMapDepo = mutableMapOf()
                mutableMapDepoKod = mutableMapOf()

                for (i in list) {
                    listHedefDepo.add(i.DEPOAD)
                    mutableMap[i.DEPOAD] = i.DEPOKOD
                    mutableMapDepoKod[i.DEPOKOD] = i.DEPOAD


                }
                val depoArrayAdapter = activity?.let {
                    ArrayAdapter(it, R.layout.view_spinner_dropdown_item, listHedefDepo)
                }!!
                println("depolar :${mutableMap.entries}")
                detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.setAdapter(depoArrayAdapter)
               detayRowBinding.spinnerHedefDepoSec.onItemClickListener =
                    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
                        depoAd = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                        depoKod = mutableMap[depoAd].toString()
                        view?.hideKeyboard()
                    }
            },
            empty = {
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
                toastWarning(str(R.string.depoyok))
                binding.emptyView.visible()
            },
            error = {
                listHedefDepo = ArrayList()
                binding.spinnerKaynakDepoSec.setAdapter(null)
                toastError(it)
            }
        )
    }
```

XML Codes :

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilDepo"
            style="@style/textInputLayoutStyleDrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/textInputHeight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mr_card_list"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:hint="@string/hedef_depo_seciniz">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/spinnerHedefDepoSec"
                style="@style/r14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I couldn't solve the problem. I tried removing the inputtype part but still couldn't solve it